# Reading in data inside a function

Tags: r, function

Here is a function that i am trying to execute, My data directory and base directory have the correct file paths.

```
loadDIH = function(){ 
##----
##++++
## Target variable: Days in hospital Year 2
dih.Y2    <- read.csv(file = paste(dataDir, "DaysInHospital_Y2.csv", sep=""),
        colClasses = c("factor", "integer", "integer"),
        comment.char = "")
## Days in hospital Year 3
dih.Y3    <- read.csv(file = paste(dataDir, "DaysInHospital_Y3.csv", sep=""),
        colClasses = c("factor", "integer", "integer"),
        comment.char = "")

   return(list(dih.Y2,dih.Y3))
}

>return(list(dih.Y2,dih.Y3))
Error: object 'dih.Y2' not found
```

My data directory and base directory have the correct file paths because when i execute the code with out using the function it reads the data eg.

```
dih.Y2    <- read.csv(file = paste(dataDir, "DaysInHospital_Y2.csv", sep=""),
        colClasses = c("factor", "integer", "integer"),
        comment.char = "")

dih.Y3    <- read.csv(file = paste(dataDir, "DaysInHospital_Y3.csv", sep=""),
        colClasses = c("factor", "integer", "integer"),
        comment.char = "")


>dih.Y2
```

This returns dih.Y2

Any thought or ideas on how to execute this as a function?
I appreciate any help?

Answer (score 4):

Objects created inside a function are visible only within that function. You'll want to use an explicit `return` statement, like

```
return(list(dih.Y2,dih.Y3))
```

Moreover, you'd probably benefit from spending some time reading the R manual section on [scope](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Scope).

There is also the global assignment operator `<<-`, but it's use is often frowned upon. You should probably stick with the way R wants to be used, and have functions return the values you want explicitly.

In your example, it would look like this:

```
loadDIH = function(){ 
##----
##++++
## Target variable: Days in hospital Year 2
dih.Y2    <- read.csv(file = paste(dataDir, "DaysInHospital_Y2.csv", sep=""),
        colClasses = c("factor", "integer", "integer"),
        comment.char = "")
## Days in hospital Year 3
dih.Y3    <- read.csv(file = paste(dataDir, "DaysInHospital_Y3.csv", sep=""),
        colClasses = c("factor", "integer", "integer"),
        comment.char = "")

   return(list(dih.Y2,dih.Y3))
}
```

Then the command,

```
foo <- loadDIH(...)
```

will result in `foo` being a list containing `dih.Y2` and `dih.Y3`.

This kind of stuff is covered extensively in some of the [manuals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html) for beginners.

Comment: I tried using that return statement, Still no luck, I know its something small that needs fixing, Will figure it out eventually.lol

Comment: @user1250865 No, you completely misunderstood. The `return` statement goes _inside_ your function, in order to, you know, _return_ a value. Try reading some documentation, starting with `?return`.